# What does steering angle mean?

Tags: navigation, flight-planning, flight-path

I'm reading the [UAVSAR data format](http://uavsar.jpl.nasa.gov/science/documents/polsar-format.html) and in **File Naming Convention** section is said that if we take a typical file name:

```
Dthvly_34501_08038_006_080731_L090HH_XX_01.slc
```

as the name that follows

```
Dthvly_34501_08038_006_080731_L  (090)  HH_XX_01.slc
```

The three digits that are in parentheses, is the **steering angle**.
And for the above file name, we have:

> Dthvly is the site name, 345 degrees is the heading of UAVSAR in
>   flight, with a counter of 01, the flight was the thirty-eighth flight
>   by UAVSAR in 2008, this data take was the sixth data take during the
>   flight, the data was acquired on July 31, 2008 (UTC), the frequency
>   band was L-band, **pointing at perpendicular to the flight heading (90
>   degrees counterclockwise)**, this file contains the HH data, this is the
>   first interation of processing, cross talk calibration has not been
>   applied, and the data type is SLC.

What is **steering angle**?

Please explain very simply because I'm not very familiar with aviation concepts. I just want to have a sense and intuition about of the aircraft **steering angle**.

Comment: The only thing that the internet seems to reference with that is the angle of the nose gear from being centered ( "centered" meaning that the plane would be going straight if it was on the ground).  Does that sound like it fits what you're looking at?

Comment: The steering angle, in these files, refers to radar beam steering. In this case the radar is rotated 90 degrees ccw with respect to the flight heading, effectively looking into the 255 degrees direction. Voted to close as off-topic / too specific

Comment: @JayCarr At first I thought it is the central angle of the curved path of the plane? but three things make me dubious. 1- Plane is not always on a curved path, so we don't always need to report steering angle.      2- In order to uniquely specify the curved path, central angle is not enough. We need the radius of the curve, too. Then why don't we report that radius in file's name?      3-  the bold center in the quoted part `pointing at perpendicular to the flight heading (90 degrees counterclockwise)` also makes me dubious

Comment: @DeltaLima what does ccw mean? Also I thing it's not an off-topic question. Because at the first look, we think steering angle definition is the one said by Jay Carr. I also searched for that https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=aircraft+steering+angle and I thought it should be related to navigation and aviation

Comment: ok I understood. ccw means counter clock-wise

Comment: CCW = counterclockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steering angle, according to the text you bolded:

> **pointing at perpendicular to the flight heading (90 degrees counterclockwise)**

means the steering angle `090` is the angle, relative to the flight heading counterclockwise, that the data sample was taken.

If the flight heading was 345 degrees, 90 degrees counter clockwise (CCW) is 255 degrees.  This steering angle has no aviation context and is just a relative offset from the aircraft heading for data acquisition (which in this case sounds like a radar sample).